# Wordpress: Crop Image with fixed value and save it in media library

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a site that periodically get snapshot from a selection of website.
Each image has been cropped in a different way and I've saved the crop data for each.
Every day the website gets the updated snapshot for each site and I want the crop to be apply to the new image.
I found I can crop calling an image editor instance

```
$img = wp_get_image_editor( ABSPATH.'wp-content/uploads/temp/site_img.jpg' );
if ( ! is_wp_error( $img ) ) {
    $img->crop( 130, 110, 107, 145, NULL, NULL, false );
}
```

How should I use crop and save the cropped image to the media library?

**SOLUTION**

```
$image->save( 'new_image.jpg' );
```

Now it works!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was easy:

```
$image->save( 'new_image.jpg' );
```