# Wordpress: how to hook to set featured image

Tags: wordpress, hook

Does anybody know how to add an action when the featured image is being attached to a post?
I searched around but I can't find what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analyzing all the ajax calls I found that I can hook into the action `get-post-thumbnail-html/`

This is the answer:

```
jQuery(function ($) { 
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings)  {
        if (typeof settings.data==='string' && /action=get-post-thumbnail-html/.test(settings.data) && xhr.responseJSON && typeof xhr.responseJSON.data==='string') {
            // do whatever
           }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you clarify the goal here? I think I might want to do something similar, but I'm not sure it's the same thing. Are you hooking into the action when a user selects or uploads an image but before the publish or save draft button is clicked?

Comment: Actually, I just tried it and yes, that's what you're doing. There was a typo in your code though (extra bracket) and I fixed it. Were you able to then get the image and save it as the featured image outside of WP's standard way? If so, do you mind sharing how?

Comment: Yes, I'was able to hook into that function and to set the image, I needed to save a crop information for the thumbnail that was automatically set by an external call. It's passed a lot of time and I have to look back in that work files... but yes, I can share the solution with you if you need it... maybe you can create a question, otherwise where can I post that?

Comment: this was another of my questions related to the same problem... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41395663/wordpress-crop-image-with-fixed-value-and-save-it-in-media-library

Comment: Thanks! I actually went a different route using a meta field and saving to featured image, so no worries, but this question and your linked questions are helpful and I will save them to reference later. :)

Comment: Thanks, very useful for keeping additional settings added with the hook 'admin_post_thumbnail_html' when we modify the featured image.